Entity Framework Core : Select() - change a column name
I have the following select:
var allUsers = await dbContext.AppUsers
    .Where(u => allUserIds.Contains(u.IdentityUsersId))
    .Include(u => u.Following)
    .Select(u => new
    {
        u.Name,
        u.Email,
        u.Phone!.FormattedNumber,
        u.Following
    })
    .ToListAsync();

It returns an object where the 3rd property is named FormattedNumber. Is there a way to have the property named PhoneNumber?
Update: I added C# as a tag because now that I see the answer, this is more of a dynamic objects question. And I think this is a useful Q&A to show how dynamic objects are defined in an EF select.

You can name your property PhoneNumber = u.Phone!.FormattedNumber,

@jeb thank you. I'm still learning these dynamic objects. If you make that an answer, happy to accept it.

You can name the propertys of your anonymous type anyway you want to:
.Select(u => new
    {
        u.Name,
        u.Email,
        PhoneNumber = u.Phone!.FormattedNumber,
        u.Following
    })
    .ToListAsync();

